# Contravariance interface implementation order

Tags: c#, interface

Take this piece of code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    interface IVisitable<T> { 
        void Accept(object o);
    }

    interface IVisitor<in T> {
        void Visit(T t);
    }

    class IntAndDoubleVisitable: IVisitable<int>, IVisitable<double>
    {
        public void Accept(object o) {
            if (o is IVisitor<IntAndDoubleVisitable>) {
                ((IVisitor<IntAndDoubleVisitable>)o).Visit(this);
            }
        }
    }

    class SingleVisitor<T>: IVisitor<T> {
        public void Visit(T visitor) {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).FullName);
        }
    }

    class DoubleVisitor1: IVisitor<IVisitable<int>>, IVisitor<IVisitable<double>> {
        void IVisitor<IVisitable<int>>.Visit(IVisitable<int> t) {
            Console.WriteLine("Int");
        }

        void IVisitor<IVisitable<double>>.Visit(IVisitable<double> t) {
            Console.WriteLine("Double");
        }
    }

    class DoubleVisitor2: IVisitor<IVisitable<double>>, IVisitor<IVisitable<int>> {
        void IVisitor<IVisitable<int>>.Visit(IVisitable<int> t) {
            Console.WriteLine("Int");
        }

        void IVisitor<IVisitable<double>>.Visit(IVisitable<double> t) {
            Console.WriteLine("Double");
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var visitable = new IntAndDoubleVisitable();
        visitable.Accept(new SingleVisitor<IVisitable<int>>()); // Fine
        visitable.Accept(new SingleVisitor<IVisitable<double>>()); // Fine
        visitable.Accept(new DoubleVisitor1()); // ?
        visitable.Accept(new DoubleVisitor2()); // ?
    }
}
```

How will the least two calls be handled?

By making few tests, I can say that the first call (DoubleVisitor1) writes "Int" and the second writes "Double", but I couldn't find anything online except a post by Eric Lippert teasing about what would the same situation cause if used in IEnumerable. It would be nice to have a reference from the language or from Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Which was the post you're referencing?

Comment: @EricLippert https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/09/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-ten-dealing-with-ambiguity/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the IL level, the behavior is defined in ECMA 335 (II.12.2) to be in declaration order *referring to the IL declaration tables*. However, AFAIK C# doesn't formally guarantee to preserve interface declaration order *from C# into the IL*, so:

- it happens to *be* declaration order *today*
- but it would be prudent to consider this an undefined behavior, and not rely on it
- and in particular, note that C# can have undefined declaration order *anyway* (see: `partial class`)

Comment: Can you clarify your last point? What I get from your wording is that if I declare partial classes and each partial class declares a base interface then the order is undefined (and may change between compilations).

Comment: @marco6 ok; you have two code files - one has `partial class Foo : IX {...}` - one has `partial class Foo : IY {...}`. Now; what is the declaration order of the interfaces that `Foo` implements, **referring to the C# specification**? They aren't likely to change between compilations, and the answer is *probably* "files are processed alphabetically" for SDK-style projects, and "files are processed in the order they are in the project file" otherwise, but... now show me where the C# specification says *anything* about file order and interface declaration order...

Comment: yeah I would have expected something like that. I cannot show anything by the way as I didn't find anything in the first place (and that's why I posted this question).

Comment: @marco6: Marc is of course correct, and you would do well to avoid this sort of code entirely. This is one of the few places in C# where the compiler emits code with implementation-defined behaviour; I considered adding a warning for it, but since the scenario is rare and undesirable I believe we decided against it.

Comment: @MarcGravell: If I recall correctly, the original C# compiler compiled the files in whatever order they came out of the file system if you did something like compiling `*.cs`, which is implementation-defined. I would *guess*, but have no specific knowledge, that when the C# compiler was hardened to ensure that the same inputs would produce the same outputs, that either the compilation order was canonicalized, or, more likely, that the IL/metadata emitting algorithms work out a canonical order by some magic.

Comment: @EricLippert seems likely, but again: that sounds like a compiler implementation detail, not a specification guarantee.

Comment: @EricLippert of course, it is also pretty safe to say: A) changing it could result in very odd and unexpected behavior in existing code that didn't understand the problems - errors that are subtle and expensive to track down, B) the compiler team understand the problem *very well*, A+B => C) it will almost certainly never change, so for all practical purposes D) it *becomes* reliable precisely because of how unreliable it is!

Comment: @MarcGravell: That is a good meta-point, yes. There are several places for example where the compiler does not quite implement the spec, and I made for darn sure that it will always fail to implement the spec in exactly the same way. :)